# Динамическое меню MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Нужно создать меню, одна часть которого будет загружаться при запуске программы, а вторая часть будет статическая. Каким образом можно это реализовать?

ViewModel:

```
private List<IPlugin> _plugins;
public List<IPlugin> Plugins { get => _plugins; set { Set(ref _plugins, value); } }
```

View:

```
<Menu Name="MainMenu" Grid.Row="0">    
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding mMenuFileOpen_Click}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="{Binding mMenuFileSave_Click}"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Plugins">
        /*Здесь должны быть плагины*/            
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз вы используете MVVM, тогда привязывайтесь через `ItemsSource`:

```
<MenuItem Header="Plugins" ItemsSource="{Binding Plugins}"/>
```

Чтобы настроить отображение плагинов, можно задать `DisplayMemberPath`. Например, если название плагина находится в свойстве `Name`, используйте

```
<MenuItem Header="Plugins" ItemsSource="{Binding Plugins}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Если вам нужно что-то более сложное, используйте `ItemTemplate`:

```
<MenuItem Header="Plugins" ItemsSource="{Binding Plugins}">
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontStyle="Italic"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Дополню вопрос. У каждого плагина будет две команды Run и Stop. А так же нужно отображение того, включен ли он.

Comment: @tmoha: (1) Это уже новый вопрос. (2) Ну вынесите состояние включён или нет в свойство, и вяжитесь к нему. А команды передавайте в виде `ICommand`.